# KOrganizer: CalDav calendar disappeared

Tags: calendar, korganizer

due to unknown reason my CalDav calendar disappeared from my calendar management (overview) in KOrganizer. Strange fact is, that the calendar is still present under settings -> KOrganizer set up -> generally -> calendar. The status there is ready. Any ideas how to fix this?

What I did so far:

- purge & re-install KOrganizer
- deleted all calendars and set them up again

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04.4 & KDE 4.13.3

In addition: How can I set up a new local calendar?

Thanks.

Comment: After long research I found a fix by my own.
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=97252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time of research I found this solution:

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=97252#p311733

> The reason here was: In owncloud I had calendars and addressbooks with the same name. KDE was not able to deal with this, while e.g. caldav/carddav on android did fine. Maybe it would work with different ressources, but I just renamed the addressbooks.

Thanks to: mlorenzen

If this should not help try this in addition:

- I reinstall akonadi-server & akonadi-backend-mysql
- I deleted all files in /home/.kde/share/config
  **(be carefull, your mail account information are there as well)**