# Korganizer adds google account but does not display it

Tags: google-calendar, korganizer

In Korganizer, I can add my Google calendar account, but it does not appear in the calendar list of the main window (see screenshot) and the events are not shown.

[image]

I have tried to:

- reinstall Korganizer
- remove all calendars and re-add them
- resintall akonadi-server and akonadi-backend-mysql as in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740919/korganizer-caldav-calendar-disappeared)

I am surprised because Korganizer used to work flawlessly with google before I formatted my system and installed Ubuntu 21

Thank you to the community for the kind help!

Comment: Seems to be a bug in KOrganizer. I am also affected by this.
Here is the link to the bug report with more details: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449024

Comment: issue solved by upgrading to ubuntu 21